# Activiti - How to create subtask through API

Tags: activiti

I'm having a situation where user will be displayed with its task. User will be having option to create subtasks of that task dynamically. User should be able to create "n" number of tasks.
I could see getSubTasks() in runtimeService to return list of subtasks. But I'm not getting how to create/add subtasks to tasks.
Is there a way to do this with the help of activiti api's?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        // save task
        Task newTask = taskService.newTask();
        newTask.setParentTaskId(parentTask.getId());
        newTask.setName("MySubTask");
        taskService.saveTask(newTask);
```